# Vector Iterators of Shared Pointers

Tags: templates, c++11, vector, iterator, shared-ptr

I'm trying to get an iterator to my vector of **shared_ptr**. Its giving me 2 compile errors:

```
syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'begin'
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

In the code, if I replace the vector's entry type with string or something basic, it compiles. [of course thats not what I want]. Whats going on?

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

template<class _Kty, class _Ty> class MyClass {
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<std::pair<_Kty, _Ty>> Entry;

    // Vector containing pairs of the key & value
    std::vector<Entry> container;

    // Beginning iterator to the vector part
    std::vector<Entry>::iterator begin() noexcept {
        return containervector.begin();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<Entry>::iterator` is a *dependent* name.

Use `typename` as a hint for the compiler regarding that nested `::iterator` *something*:

```
   typename std::vector<Entry>::iterator begin() noexcept {
// ^^^^^^^^
```

***Q & A section:***

> *Why `typedef std::string Entry;` works without `typename` ?*

`std::string` is an explicit instantiation of a template `std::basic_string<char>`, hence, the compiler knows everything about this type and its nested member classes.

> *Why did I need a `typename` for the `shared_ptr` version of code?*

This is because what is hidden behind `std::vector<Entry>` depends on the arguments supplied to the template. That is, the `std::vector<Entry>::iterator` will vary depending on what the `Entry` is, and the `Entry` itself utilizes template parameters (because it has `std::pair<_Kty, _Ty>`), and the `iterator` member may *not exist* at all, or it may be e.g. a static object instead of a type. `typename` is a hint for the compiler.

Comment: that worked! but I have another question. I changed the typedef line to: typedef std::string Entry; & it compiled. Why did I need a typename for the shared_ptr version of code? [& not the string version]